# Are Python global variables thread-safe?

Tags: python, mongodb, tornado

edit: im asking if global variables are safe in a single-threaded web framework like tornado

im using the mongoengine orm, which gets a database connection from a global variable:

```
_get_db() # gets the db connection
```

im also using tornado, a single-threaded python web framework. in one particular view, i need to grab a database connection and dereference a `DBRef` object [similar to a foreign key]:

```
# dereference a DBRef
_get_db().dereference(some_db_ref)
```

since the connection returned by `_get_db` is a global var, is there a possibility of collision and the wrong value being returned to the wrong thread?

Comment: Appears this has more to do with the specific library than with global variables.

Comment: Do mongodb specify whether _get_db is threadsafe?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming MongoEngine is wrapping PyMongo (and I believe it is), then you should be fine. PyMongo is completely thread-safe.

Comment: yes, it wraps pymongo, but stores the pymongo.Connection instance in a global variable

Comment: That's fine then - it's safe to share a Connection instance.

Answer (score 3):

Threads are always required to hold the GIL when interacting with Python objects. The namespace holding the variables is a Python object (either a frameobject or a dict, depending on what kind of variable it is.) It's always safe to get or set variables in multiple threads.  You will never get garbage data.

However, the usual race conditions do apply as to which object you get, or which object you replace when you assign. A statement like `x += 1` is *not* thread-safe, because a different thread can run between the get and the store, changing the value of `x`, which you would then overwrite.

Comment: are you saying that any function or class method with `x += 1` is not thread-safe?

Comment: He's saying that setting global variables in threaded python can fail - another thread can set the variable to a different value just after. If you rely on the value being set during a block of code, you should use locks. It's thread-safe in that you won't get seg-faults, but not in the sense that you may get unexpected values. Looping on lists and dicts are classic examples where you can get into trouble - eg a dict key may disappear unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1):

No, but locks are pretty straightforward to use in python.   Use the try:  finally:  pattern to ensure that a lock is released after you modify your global variable.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing about globals that makes them any more or less thread safe than any other variables. Whether or not it's possible for an operation to fail or return incorrect results when run in different threads, the best practice is that you should *protect data shared between threads.*

If I'm reading you right, you're asking if a variable is safe in a single-threaded environment. In this case, where data is *not* shared between concurrent processes, the variable is safe (after all, there's nothing else running that may interrupt it).